# whereIn function within a sub query within eloquent doesnt filter any records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Prize, Ticket and User model. A prize can have many tickets, and a ticket can only be associated to one User.

Each Prize will have one Winning Ticket, what I am trying to do is list all my Users that have a winning Ticket like so:

```
$winning_tickets = Prize::WinnerSelected()->get('ticket_winner_id')->pluck('ticket_winner_id');

$users = User::with(['tickets' => function($query) use ($winning_tickets) {
     $query->whereIn('id', $winning_tickets);
}])->get();
```

`$winning_tickets` returns an array of winning ticket ids, but the $users collection returns ALL my users, even users that have no ticket records.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks, cant believe I missed this. I actually have other methods that do exactly this. Can you convert this into an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with()` doesn't actually filter the `User` Collection being returned. To do that, you need to use `whereHas()`:

```php
$winningTickets = Prize::WinnerSelected()->get('ticket_winner_id')->pluck('ticket_winner_id');

$users = User::whereHas('tickets', function($query) use ($winningTickets) {
     $query->whereIn('id', $winningTickets);
})->get();
```

Now, the `$users` Collection will only contain `User` records that have one or more `Ticket` records matching the given `ticket_winner_id` in `$winning_tickets`.

If you need to, you can use both `with()` and `whereHas()` to filter *and* eager load the associated `Ticket` records:

```php
$winningTickets = Prize::WinnerSelected()->get('ticket_winner_id')->pluck('ticket_winner_id');

$filterClause = function ($query) use ($winningTickets) {
  return $query->whereIn('id', $winningTickets);
};

$users = User::with(['tickets' => $filterClause])
->whereHas('tickets', $filterClause)
->get();
```

Define the  the `function ($query)` as a reusable clause to avoid repetition, and voila!

Sidenote, you don't need to chain `->get()` into `->pluck()`; both Builder and Collection classes have a `->pluck()` method, so this is valid:

```php
$winningTickets = Prize::WinnerSelected()->pluck('ticket_winner_id');
```